# How to refer to a cell when the address is in a variable

Tags: libreoffice-calc

For example, in an expression, instead of writing the address `A1`, how can I write something like: `A(B1)` with `B1 = 1`.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I think another way of explaining what INDIRECT does is this way:

It turns text into a range, if that range is valid.

E.g. If you have text A1, it'll reference to A1. If you have text C2:C100, you'll get this as range.

Now, one of the most common ways in excel to generate text in the form of ranges is to concatenate. So that if you concatenate `A` and `1` (`CONCATENATE("A","1")`), you get A1.

And you can use a reference in this concatentate. Let's say that cell B1 contains 1.

```
=CONCATENATE("A",B1)
```

gives the text A1.

Hence, to get the cell A1, you would be able to use:

```
=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",B1))
```

Except that the `CONCATENATE()` function now is a bit long, but don't fret! You can use `&`:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&B1)
```

Works just as well.

If you have something more complex like you have `C` in A1 and `32` in B1, to refer to cell `C32`, you can do:

```
=INDIRECT(A1&B1)
```

Which gives `=INDIRECT("C"&"32")`, `=INDIRECT("C32")` and finally `=C32`

Comment: To evaluate sum from A1 to A9, given that B1 contains 1 and B2 contains 9 do: `=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",B1)),INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",B2))`.

Comment: @Adobe Hmm, that actually will add A1 and A9 and *not* A1 **to** A9. In that case, I would find simpler to do `=SUM(INDIRECT("A"&B1&":A"&B2))`.

Comment: Sorry: should have semicolon in the middle: `=SUM(INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",B1)):INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("A",B2))`. Your version is much simpler though.

Comment: Why do you use strings and CONCATENATE, instead of ADDRESS()? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs INDIRECT gives you a **reference** from text, ADDRESS gives you a **text** from given coordinates (only numbers).

Comment: @Jerry I know that -- `ADDRESS(B1,1)` has the same value as `CONCATENATE("A",B1)` if B1 contains an integer. However, if cell B1 contains the value "A3" then the ADDRESS version will throw an error while the CONCATENATE version will access a random cell.
Also ADDRESS lets you access columns indirectly.
Also² one might assume that the spreadsheet is able to internally optimize INDIRECT(ADDRESS(…)) so that it doesn't have to create and discard a string every time you calculate a reference; presumably such is not done with INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(…)).

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs Sorry, now I understand what you were trying to say. I was trying to keep to the OP as much as possible, that is, given a column reference and a row number stored in a cell, get the reference of the two combined. If I may stretch the original example, having XCQ and 1 in cell B1, I should get $XCQ$1 as reference result. It is trivial using the method I described, but not as straightforward with ADDRESS simply because you first need to convert XCQ into a number, 16319. Granted that's unlikely to happen, but it can get cumbersome if you have various column references to convert.

Answer (score 7):

`INDIRECT' is the function you need to use.

From the [documentation](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Spreadsheet_Functions#INDIRECT):

### Syntax:

**INDIRECT(Ref; A1)**

Ref represents a reference to a cell or an area (in text form) for which to return the contents.

A1 (optional) - if set to 0, the R1C1 notation is used. If this parameter is absent or set to another value than 0, the A1 notation is used.

### Example

**=INDIRECT(A1)** equals 100 if A1 contains C108 as a reference and cell C108 contains a value of 100.

**=SUM(INDIRECT("a1:" & ADDRESS(1;3)))** totals the cells in the area of A1 up to the cell with the address defined by row 1 and column 3. This means that area A1:C1 is totaled.

Answer (score 2):

=OFFSET(B1, 0, 1)

OFFSET(reference, row offset, column offset, area height defaults to 1, area width defaults to 1)

**Example 1.** We have multiplication table and need to find the answer for some stupid reason with OFFSET.

```
   A   B  C  D  E  F
1      1  2  3  4  5
     ---------------
2  1 | 1  2  3  4  5
3  2 | 2  4  6  8 10
4  3 | 3  6  9 12 15
5  4 | 4  8 12 16 20
6  5 | 5 10 15 20 25
```

Let's say we need 2x4
=OFFSET(A1, 2, 4)
or in this case switching the numbers works equally well
=OFFSET(A1, 4, 2)

**Example 2.**
Let's calculate sum of all the numbers in the previous multiplication table which are for 2 or larger.
=SUM(OFFSET(A1, 2, 2, 4, 4))